# Example sentence that uses “entsprechend” as adjective

Tags: grammar, adjective, adverb

According to my online dictionary *entsprechend* as adjective means:

> appropriate, respective, corresponding

and as adverb:

> accordingly, proportionately

As examples, the following sentences are given:

> Die Fehlerquelle muss entsprechend geprüft werden.
>
> In diesem Fall hat sich X bemüht, eine Alternative zu finden, die Ihre Reise so wenig wie möglich beeinträchtigt, und wir haben Ihren Reiseplan entsprechend aktualisiert.

In both cases, I assume that *entsprechend* is used as an adverb and means *accordingly.*

Can anyone give me an example sentence in which *entsprechend* is used as an adjective?

Answer (score 3):

For many words, [the online Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/entsprechend_adaequat_zustaendig) gives neat examples of usage.

Another example:

> Um 50g Abecedol herstellen zu können, muss zunächst die entsprechende Menge an Alphabetan opequriert werden.

There are a few possible reasons why it is not stated how much Alphabetan is exactly needed. Maybe it's an unsightly long decimal number, or maybe mentioning *that* something needs to be opequrized in the first place is more important than the exact amount.

Note that *entsprechend* is the present participle of *entsprechen*.